# How to update a JSF form from the bean?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

What I am trying to do is get the user to click a button which opens a dialog asking do you want to Start? Yes-No.

If they select Yes, a value in the database is set to 1, otherwise it is left at 0.

Once they click yes, a MindMap should be rendered - however, despite using what I thought was the correct option, it hasn't worked. If I refresh the page after clicking Yes, the mindmap is rendered, but I want to do it using the ajax formulation, if possible.

Here is my current code:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" 
                 message="Are you sure about starting the round?"
                 header="Initiating round" 
                 severity="alert" 
                 widgetVar="confirmation"
                 >

    <p:growl id="growl2" showDetail="true" life="3000"/>

    <p:commandButton id="confirm" 
                     value="Yes Sure" 
                     update="growl2,mmBody,mm" 
                     oncomplete="confirmation.hide(),mm.update()"
                     actionListener="#{mmBean.checkRenderMM()}"
                     />

    <p:commandButton id="decline"
                     value="Not Yet" 
                     onclick="confirmation.hide()"
                     type="button"
                     /> 

</p:confirmDialog>

<p:mindmap id="mindmap" value="#{mmBean.root}" widgetVar="mm">
  ...
</p:mindmap>
```

The Bean Code is pretty simple; just a simple check if it's true or false:

```
public Boolean checkRenderMM(){
    if ( this.cUser.getReadytobegin() != 1 ){
        this.setRenderMM( false );
    }
    else{
        this.setRenderMM( true );
    }
    return this.getRenderMM();
}
```

Get and set are standard getters and setters.

What I'm wondering is is there a way to do it from inside the bean? That is:

```
public Boolean checkRenderMM(){
    if ( this.cUser.getReadytobegin() != 1 ){
        this.setRenderMM( false );
    }
    else{
        this.setRenderMM( true );
    }

    SOME CODE THAT UPDATES THE MINDMAP COMPONENT FROM HERE

    return this.getRenderMM();
}
```

Or something along those lines.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you want/need: How to show/hide the mindmap from the primefaces confirm dialog or to update the database once clicking the confirm option?

Comment: As far as I can see you have the *MM* binded to an attribute in your bean. Having `private MindmapNode root;` you can do whatever you want with it while `checkRenderMM()` listener is processing.

Comment: Your question/requirement is hard to understand. When looking at code, isn't your whole problem just caused by using an incorrect ID in the `update`? Shouldn't the `update="growl2,mmBody,mm"` be `update="growl2,mmBody,mindmap"`?

Comment: Sorry, I had been messing around and trying a few different things first, which is why the update has the wrong id (mm being what I was calling a different form for a bit) - I was trying to update the mindmap by setting "widgetVar = mm" and calling "mm.update()", or trying to figure out the correct syntax for that.

In any case, after messing around some more it now works - though I had to update the form the mindmap was in rather than the mindmap directly (which I suppose makes a lot of sense, but didn't work as I first tried it).

I apologise for my unclear question, I will work on that.